# Try/catch blocks and if statements in rainfall-averaging program

Tags: java, if-statement, try-catch, average, block

I am coding a rainfall averaging program. The program lets the user input a file name and if the file cannot be found, then the user is prompted to reenter the file name. The user gets 4 tries before the application quits without processing the data, and the application itself is a rainfall averaging program like I said.

```
package experiment8;
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class Exceptions
{
  static  Scanner inFile;
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    int fileTry = 0;
    String fileName;
    Scanner inName = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter file name>");
    fileName = inName.nextLine();
    boolean fileOk;
    do
    {
      fileOk =  false;
      try
        {

          Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
          Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("inData.dat"));
          fileOk = true;
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException error)
        {

          System.out.println("Reenter file name>");
          fileName = inName.nextLine();
          fileTry++;
        }
    } while (!fileOk && fileTry < 4);
    PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("outData.dat"));

    if (fileOk && fileTry < 4 )
    {   
        int numDays = 0;
        double average;
        double inches = 0.0;
        double total = 0.0;
        while (inFile.hasNextFloat())
      {
        inches = inFile.nextFloat();
        total = total + inches;
          outFile.println(inches);
          numDays++;
      }

      if (numDays == 0) 
        System.out.println("Average cannot be computed " +
                         " for 0 days."); 
      else
      {
        average = total / numDays;
        outFile.println("The average rainfall over " +  
          numDays + " days is " + average); 
      }
      inFile.close();
    }
    else

      System.out.println("Error");
    outFile.close();
  }
}
```

I am trying to code this program so when I input the correct file name, "inData.dat", I will get the proper output. However, when I do this, I continue to get prompted to reenter the file name for the next 3 times, after which I get the "Error" message. Is there something wrong with my try/catch blocks or if statements?

Comment: It seems like you should be using your filename variable instead of the hard coded “inData.dat”

Answer (score 0):

I have two questions about your code.

1. What is the purpose of the line `Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);` in the try-block?
2. Why do you have an if statement check `if (fileOk && fileTry < 4)` after the do-while block for getting the file? It seems redundant. The do-while block checks for the same condition. Once the program gets to the location of this if-statement this condition must have been met. If it wasn't, the do-while would have run again.

It is possible for you to get to a case where the do-while ends because the file was found, and the condition of this if-statement is false because fileTry < 4. I don't understand why you would care about the fileTry counter once you found the correct file. If the user tried to enter the file name 4 times and got it correct on the last try, the program will go to the else part of this if-statement and print "Error".

Answer (score 0):

There are  lot of issues with your program. Here are a few to get you on the way.

1. The file `inData.dat` does not exist. Please create it in the appropriate place.
2. After you get over that hump, there would be a Null Pointer on Line 40: `inFile` is null.

My recommendation is to open it in an editor such as *Visual Studio Code*. It would point you to a lot of warnings and you could debug your program as well.